# Why does proximity to a superconductor open a gap in the surface states of topological insulators

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-insulators

I have read in many places that the gapless surface states of 3D topological insulators are robust to perturbations which do not break time-reversal symmetry.

I have recently also seen many papers (such as http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0842) on topological insulators in proximity to a superconductor. They all predict that the surface states will get gapped and that superconductivity is induced at the surface.

But I am not able to reconcile the two issues. Superconductivity does not break time-reversal symmetry. Then why is a gap produced in the surface states?

Comment: Well, superconductors are famously known to have a gap, no ? So by proximity effect they share this gap with the metal, or semiconductor in contact with them, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

If time-reversal symmetry is broken at the surface of a topological insulator, a gap could open at the Dirac point of the topological surface state. The Dirac point, where forward- and backward-moving electrons have the same energy, is located at a time-reversal invariant momentum point (also called a Kramer's point) in the reciprocal space (the crystal momentum is zero or zero plus an integer multiple of a reciprocal lattice vector). The Kramer's pair of surface state branches defined for forward- and backward-moving electrons, which would otherwise be degenerate at k = 0, are no longer degenerate as a result of a time-reversal symmetry breaking interaction which couples differently to different spins.

For a superconductor, the energy gap forms at the Fermi energy (binding energy = 0). The condensate of Cooper pairs has a lower energy than the Fermi energy of the normal metal state, while unpaired electron states exist above the Fermi energy. Hence, a gap forms. The hope is that Cooper pairs will tunnel from a superconductor onto the surface of a topological insulator in proximity to it, creating a similar gap in the topological surface state.

So, these are two distinct kinds of gaps in different regions of the band structure which signify very different kinds of order.

Answer (score 1):

The BiSb type topological insulators are also protected by particle-number/charge conservation symmetry which a superconductor would break. http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2686